# Show that the polynomial $x^8 -x^7 +x^2 -x +15$ has no real root.

Tags: polynomials, roots

Please check if my method is correct.
Solution : Let $$f(x) = x^8 - x^7 + x^2 -x +15 $$
Now, let $g(x)= x^8 -x^7=x^7(x - 1)$ and $h(x)= x^2 -x=x(x-1)$.
Thus, $$f(x)=g(x) + h(x) + 15$$

On analyzing $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ we see that both the functions are negative between $0$ and $1$  and the maximum negative value of both the functions do not exceed $-1$. Thus, the minimum value of $f(x)$ is not less than $13$. Hence, $f(x)$ has no real root.
Q.E.D

Comment: The main problem is proving your "Analysis" of the polynomials. Prove it and you're done.

Comment: the polynomial has only complex roots

Comment: @HasanSaad:I left the analysis because I am too lazy to type! :P The analysis of $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ can be done by finding minima using calculus, which is pretty elementary I guess! :)

Comment: As long as that part is correct, your proof is correct. The gist of the problem lies there, I believe.